# Append .xls Information to .csv File - VBA

Tags: vba, csv, append

Say that I create an array that copy's from a .xls file in VBA and want to APPEND that information to a .csv file somewhere on my drive. How do I do this? Mind you, I want it to append to the first blank row. Thanks,

```
Do While wb.Sheets(1).Cells(wb_i, 1) <> ""

    For i = 1 To 13
        transfer_array(1, i) = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(wb_i, i).Value
    Next i

'THIS WILL BE WHERE I OPEN AND APPEND TO THE CSV FILE
```

Comment: There are numerous examples of this on the site.  What have you tried?

Comment: I set mainwb to be the .csv file. And then I did this. For i = 1 To 13
        mainwb.Worksheets("test").Cells(main_i, i).Value = transfer_array(1, i) & ""
        Next i                                                                                               This let's me paste into the csv file. The "" allows me to seperate the columns (somehow). But now the csv file has a limit of 1Million rows! How can this be?